# How to change ActionBar's bottom bar color

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android

Is it possible to change ActionBar's bottom bar color? I want to have one color in ActionBar's **TOP BAR** (Red) and another color in **Bottom BAR** (white).

[image: ActionBar]

Comment: I also have the same issue to overcome. Have you found the answer? any help please..

Comment: this cant be done , I did not found any solution yet